# Delete slide from TypoScript variable

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I want to delete the slide function from my TypoScript varaible. What should I remove exactly?

```
hidebox = TEXT
hidebox {
    value =
    override {
        required = 1
        data = levelfield : -1 , showbox, slide
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could describe your goal in more plain words not directly referring to TypoScript features. Then you are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the slide is given with:

```
data = levelfield : -1 , showbox, slide
```

to remove the sliding you have to change it to the simple field access:

```
field = showbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bernd,

Then i have changed the code to this :

```
hidebox = TEXT
hidebox {
   data = page : showbox
}
```